# Any multi-dimensional Ruby state machine gems?

Tags: ruby

Are there any state machine gems that support more than one dimension (field, column, attribute...) of state? I skimmed the docs of the most popular ones, and also tried googling, but could find no evidence or leads.

All current popular state machine gems are built around a single string field for state, which is insufficient to represent all the state for more complex state machines.